# How to use lists outside of for loop?

Tags: python, list

I´m trying to monitor prices on the eshop. How I do it is, I´m webscraping the prices, then wait some time, do it again and compare the lists with prices if anything changed. But my lists with prices are inside the for loops and when I want to compare them outside the for loop, it says my lists are undefined. I hope you´ll understand that better with my code.

```
import requests, smtplib, time 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.sportisimo.sk/panska-vysoka-trekova-obuv/?riadenie=najlacnejs%C3%AD&dostupnost=vsetko&znacka[]=28"


getPage = requests.get(url) 
page_soup = BeautifulSoup(getPage.content, "html.parser") 
old_containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "product-box__in"})

for old_container in old_containers:
    price_container = old_container.findAll("span", {"class":"price"})
    product_price_old = price_container[0].text.strip()

    print(product_price_old)

print("---------------------") 
time.sleep(10)

getPage_new = requests.get(url) 
page_soup_new = BeautifulSoup(getPage_new.content, "html.parser") 
new_containers = page_soup_new.findAll("div", {"class": "product-box__in"})

for new_container in new_containers:
    price_container = new_container.findAll("span", {"class": "price"})
    product_price_new = price_container[0].text.strip()

    print(product_price_new)


if product_price_old != product_price_new:
    for new_container in new_containers:
        name_container = new_container.findAll("div", {"class": "product-box__name"})
        product_name = name_container[0].h2.a.text.strip()

        print(f"Zmenený produkt: {product_name}")
        print(f"Pôvodná cena: {product_price_old}")
        print(f"Nová cena: {product_price_new}")
```

The product_price_old and product_price_new writes me that they are undefined lists. How can I fix this to work, please?

Thank you

Comment: Those variables might not get defined in case the corresponding `containers` list is empty - since the loop will not run even once

Answer (score 0):

You could define start with

```
product_price_old = []
product_price new = []
```

and in the loops you could do

```
for element in price_container[0].text.strip():
    product_price_old.append(element)
    # or whatever format you want your data in
```

Comment: Yeah, I completely forgot about this. Thank you very much, it worked, with a little change.